# Play 2 Java authenticate plugin - HTTP status code response instead of redirect

Tags: java, rest, playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

We are using [Play 2 authenticate plugin](http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/) for a REST API and I would like to simply return 200 or 403 for login attempts.

The plugin's code looks like this:

```
public static Result loginAndRedirect(final Context context,
        final AuthUser loginUser) {
    storeUser(context.session(), loginUser);
    return Controller.redirect(getJumpUrl(context));
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the redirect without forking the plugin project?

Comment: Did you take a look at the Resolver ? https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/Getting%20Started.md#configure-the-resolver

Answer (score 1):

I ended up handling this at the controller:

```
public static Result login() {   
    Result r = MyUsernamePasswordAuthProvider.handleLogin(ctx());
    if (r instanceof Redirect && PlayAuthenticate.getUser(session()) != null) {
        return ok();
    }
    return forbidden();
}
```

There might be better ways to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled in the same scenario, and as nico_ekito pointed out, this can be achieved by extending `PlayAuthenticate.Resolver` and overriding:

```
@Override
    public Call afterAuth() {
        return routes.Application.restAfterAuth();
    }
```

So you can return any route of your app.