# Getting URL of current page loaded

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am asking this question because it is loosely related to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254135/play-authenticate-logout-redirect) one of my posts.

Is it possible in the play framework (2.0.4) to retrieve the URL of the page currently loaded? For example if I want to modify this method:

```
        @Override
            public Call afterAuth() {

       *IF CURRENT URL = "localhost:9000/mobile" 

                    return routes.Application.mobile_index();

       *ELSE*

                    return something.else;
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Request](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Request.html) instance to get url relative of your host:

```
public static Result someControllerMethod() {
  String uri = request().uri();
  if (routes.Application.mobile_index().url().equals(uri)) {
    return ok(views.html.mobile_main.render());
  } else {
    return ok(views.html.index.render());
  }
}
```

Actually I don't know details about your application architecture, but you can pass [Http.Context](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Context.html) to your login handler.

**update**
I don't familiar with play-authenticate module. I just looked at this source and have no idea how to access Http.Context in Resolver methods. I found only [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507605/play-2-java-authenticate-plugin-http-status-code-response-instead-of-redirect) where presented some workaround, but it doesn't look like an elegant solution.

Comment: +1 for using the request object. That should be available in most actions.